# How to add space between the Status bar and the Recyclerview card?

Tags: android, material-design

How can I add a space between the status bar and the recyclerview card?

My layout right now looks like this: [Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCtV9.png)

But I want my layout to be like this: [I want this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5zGL.png)

**My XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarPayment"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMessages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding/margin in your `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMessages"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it gave me this result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--6geEc9ie8bUlUTHBoc2NXNms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But I want this kind of result instead: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--6geEc9ie8WVdMSnVqU0wtSnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It it works, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Sure mate, I'll tick it later, after 2 mins. Stack is not allowing me to tick it right now.